# add multiple bib files dynamically using the bibtex backend

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, mac

I am writing a large document consisting of many papers with their own bibliographies structured in this way:

```
/ch1
--paper1.tex
--paper1.bib
--paper1-extra.bib
/ch2
--paper2.tex
--paper2.bib
...
document.tex
```

What I want to do is to include the bib sources dynamically (something similar to `addbibresource`) in each paper*.tex source instead of placing a command like this into the root document.tex file:

```
\bibliography{ch1/paper1,paper1-extra,ch2/paper1,...}
```

My build script is like this:

```
pdflatex document
bibtex document
pdflatex document
pdflatex document
```

Is there a way to do it using the bibtex backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\bibliography` has two jobs: Its argument tells BibTeX where to look for the references and it prints the bibliography that BibTeX generates.

It is possible to split the two jobs between two new commands. In the example below we define a `\printbibliography` that just prints the bibliography and a command `\addbibfile` that can be used multiple times anywhere in the document to add a list of `.bib` files to the list of files that BibTeX should look at. The syntax of `\addbibfile` is the same as that of the argument of `\bibliography`: You can give a comma-separated list of file names without the `.bib` extension. The file names given to `\addbibfile` are collected and written to the `.aux` for BibTeX at the end of the document.

MWE (assuming a simple bibliography setup and without any `\input`s and `\include`s, since they don't actually matter for the code presented here)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% for list manipulation
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% redefine \bibliography to only print references
% this is one part of \bibliography's job
\newcommand*{\printbibliography}{%
  \@input@{\jobname.bbl}}

% add .bib file to list of searched files
% the argument to this command is a  comma-separated
% list of .bib file names without file extension
\newcommand*{\addbibfile}{%
  \forcsvlist{\addbibfile@i}}

\newcommand*{\addbibfile@list}{}
\newcommand*{\addbibfile@i}[1]{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\addbibfile@list}
    {}
    {\listgadd{\addbibfile@list}{#1}}}

% helper macro to convert internal etoolbox list to csv
\newcommand*{\listtocsv}[2]{%
  \def#2{}%
  \forlistloop{\listtocsv@i{#2}}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\listtocsv@i}[2]{%
  \ifdefvoid{#1}
    {}
    {\appto#1{,}}
  \appto#1{#2}}

% write csv-list of .bib files to .aux
\newcommand*{\bibdata@write}[1]{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{\zap@space#1 \@empty}}%
  \fi}

\newcommand*{\addbibfile@list@csv}{}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \listtocsv{\addbibfile@list}{\addbibfile@list@csv}%
  \ifdefvoid{\addbibfile@list}
    {}
    {\expandafter\bibdata@write\expandafter{\addbibfile@list@csv}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-one.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author  = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title   = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
             electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year    = 1998,
  volume  = 19,
  number  = 4,
  pages   = {377-395},
  doi     = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
@book{nussbaum,
  author    = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title     = {Aristotle's \enquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  year      = 1978,
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  location  = {Princeton},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-two.bib}
@phdthesis{geer,
  author  = {de Geer, Ingrid},
  title   = {Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald~-- and Music:
             The {Orkney Earldom} of the Twelfth Century. {A} Musicological
             Study},
  school  = {Uppsala Universitet},
  year    = 1985,
  address = {Uppsala},
}
@book{worman,
  author    = {Worman, Nancy},
  title     = {The Cast of Character},
  year      = 2002,
  publisher = {University of Texas Press},
  address   = {Austin},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,geer,worman}

\addbibfile{\jobname-one}
\addbibfile{\jobname-two}

\bibliographystyle{plainurl}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citation and bibliography from two different files]

Note that this solution only produces one global bibliography like the normal `\bibliography`. Additional work would have to be done for split bibliographies with `multibib` and friends.